# Convert XML RSS Feed Audio Length from Bytes to Minutes/Seconds in PHP

Tags: php, xml, time, rss

I am scraping an RSS Feed which includes `<enclosure>` elements for audio files.  According to [the spec](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/rss_tag_enclosure.asp), the length is given in bytes.

```
 <enclosure url="https://www.w3schools.com/media/audio-file.m4a" length="67960845" type="audio/x-m4a" />
```

I need to convert this length into an actual measurable time (i.e. hours, minutes, seconds).  This would require knowing the bitrate (I believe), which I happen to have!  The RSS feed comes from Anchor and [according to Anchor](https://medium.com/anchor/now-your-audio-on-anchor-sounds-better-than-ever-41f89c3559ce), they sample their audio in stereo at 44.1 kHz, 128 kbit/s CBR.

I know the provided example `length="67960845"` converts to 71 minutes.  I tried to reverse engineer it but I can't really find a good formula in order to reliably convert this like:

```
<?php 
    $length = 67960845;
    $seconds = $length / ????; 
?>
```

This request is in PHP but could apply to any language scraping an RSS feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the length to bits you can then divide it by the bitrate and then get the number of seconds:

`(67960845*8)/128/1000/60 = 70.792546875`

So...

```
$length = 67960845;
$bitrate_kbps = 128;
$seconds = ceil(($length * 8) / $bitrate_kbps / 1000 / 60);
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Perfect! That's the formula I was looking for!  This is a great resource on converting audio byte size > time.